# I wanted to call function which is coming in another function as an argument, but getting error

Tags: perl, automation, logic

I have a function which is calling another function and passing arguments in it. where one of the argument is the function which is store in variable. when I am trying to call that function in another function it is throwing an error.

```
my @tst1 = ("tst1 - Checking Whether the naming format of created Directory by using tar ball is same as expected in the format of trustid_web_ yyyyMMdd-HHmmss.tar.gz and same as tar ball", "runCmd()");
@tstInfo = (\@tst1);

sub populatetestCb() {   
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $ #tstInfo; $i++) {
        $testCb {
            $i + 1
        } = $tstInfo[$i];
    }
}

populatetestCb();
$startTime = localtime();
my $tmp = 1;

while (1) {
    my $ret = getTestDetails($tmp);
    if ($ret eq 1) {
        $tStartTime = localtime();
        my $tstRes = runTest($tstDes, $tstFunction);
        $tEndTime = localtime();
        #PRINT_LOG("runTest returned $tstRes\n");
        $tmp++;
        sleep(2);
    } else {
        last;
    }
}

sub runTest {
    $tstName = $_[0];
    my $tstFunction = $_[1];
    print($tstFunction);
    my $action = \ & $tstFunction;
    $action - > ();
}
```

when I am calling `$action->()` in my `runTest` function it is throwing

```
Undefined subroutine &main::runCmd() called at testAutomation.pl line 83.
```

`my @tst1` is the array which consists test Description and the function needed to call to test it.
`populateTestCb` is the hash which is storing it and I am accessing it in `getTestDetails` function from where I wanted to call `runTest` and call particular function into it.

Comment: How do you populate `$tstFunction` on line 22? Please study [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, always use [strict](http://p3rl.org/strict) and [warnings](http://p3rl.org/warnings) in Perl.

Comment: sorry if you're not getting anything i am new to use it. the tstFunction is the variable where i am storing the name of the function which is coming as an argument

Comment: use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Copy;
use POSIX 'strftime';
use Sys::Hostname;
use Archive::Tar;
use Net::Ping;      I am using these modules on the top of my code block.

Comment: This code is very obfuscated. What is `$testcb`? Why are you using a block after the variable? Why are you storing strings in an array ref inside an array, and then pretending to loop over that array (which only has 1 element, the ref to the other array). What exactly are you trying to do? Call a function by its name in string form?

Comment: The code you posted doesn't give the output you posted. Please fix your question.

Comment: @choroba sir, my code is done, just wanted to ask something . I have one function which is checking is the connection is taking place to one particular GUI of my client and it is print " Trying to establish connection to 34.229.211.163 : 8000 ."."\n";
my $retval=system("sudo lsof -i :8000");
if ($retval==0) {
$tstResult = "pass";
    PRINT_LOG("\n"."Test Case -- [Passed]"."\n");
 return $tstResult;
} else {
 
    PRINT_LOG("\n"."Test Case -- [Failed]"."\n");
 return $tstResult; ... when i am executing it is asking me password of VM. is their any way to give it inside my script?

Comment: @choroba this is what my VM screen is asking ---[sudo] password for trustid:   , when i enter password then my code block get executed. Is their any way that i can give that password inside my perl script and it wont ask me during my automation code execution?

Comment: Don't use comments to ask unrelated questions. Ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Without [strict](http://p3rl.org/strict), calling function by name normally works:

```perl
no strict;

my $name = 'func';
$name->() and print 'ok';  # ok

sub func { 1 }
```

Under strict, it's still possible, but needs an extra step. It shouldn't be used for anything but AUTOLOAD, though.

```perl
my $name = 'func';
my $f = \&{$name};
$f->() and print 'ok';  # ok
```

Normally, you'd store a subroutine reference in a variable and call it later:

```perl
my $func = \&func;
$func->() and print 'ok';  # ok
```